# Converting a JPG to WebP in AWS Lambda using GraphicsMagick/ImageMagick packages in Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, imagemagick, graphicsmagick, aws-lambda

I am leveraging the AWS Lambda [example script](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/walkthrough-s3-events-adminuser-create-test-function-create-function.html) to resize a JPG image using Node.js and ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick libraries. I want to make a simple modification to convert the image from a JPG to a WebP format after the resize. *(GraphicsMagick does not support WebP, but ImageMagick does, which is subclassed in the script)*. This should be possible with the following block of code, as per the example in the *Buffers* section [here](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm) (which converts JPG to PNG).

```
gm('img.jpg')
.resize(100, 100)
.toBuffer('PNG',function (err, buffer) {
  if (err) return handle(err);
  console.log('done!');
})
```

When I run that block of code in my local Node.js installation (replacing PNG with WebP), it works.

When I modify the transform function (see below) of the AWS Lambda [example script](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/walkthrough-s3-events-adminuser-create-test-function-create-function.html), however, and execute it on AWS, I receive the following **"Stream yields empty buffer"** error:

```
Unable to resize mybucket/104A0378.jpg and upload to mybucket_resized/resized-104A0378.jpg due to an error: Error: Stream yields empty buffer
```

**Modified transform() function (see the line with 'webp'):**

```
function tranform(response, next) {
            gm(response.Body).size(function(err, size) {
                // Infer the scaling factor to avoid stretching the image unnaturally.
                var scalingFactor = Math.min(
                    MAX_WIDTH / size.width,
                    MAX_HEIGHT / size.height
                );
                var width  = scalingFactor * size.width;
                var height = scalingFactor * size.height;

                // Transform the image buffer in memory.
                this.resize(width, height)
                    .toBuffer('webp', function(err, buffer) {
                        if (err) {
                            next(err);
                        } else {
                            next(null, response.ContentType, buffer);
                        }
                    });
            });
        }
```

I realize that the response.ContentType is still equal to image/jpeg, but I don't think that is playing a role here. Also, I realize that I should probably convert to WebP before resizing but...baby steps!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ImageMagick has to be specifically compiled with WebP support. My experimenting seems to show that the ImageMagick on AWS Lambda is not compiled with WEBP :(

Answer (score 4):

I have encountered the same error, "Stream yields empty buffer", in other operations using gm and AWS lambda.

Turns out that the lambda container ran out of memory.

I tested this assumption using a large image that was constantly throwing an error.

When i increased the memory of the lambda function everything worked perfectly.

Hope this helps you as well

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing and I need to deploy on AWS Lambda. But to make it work locally, I had to install graphicsMagick in my OS. I am wondering how does it work as lambda for you since we can't install gm there. Could you share some insight?